# Add space after capital letter in a 2d array string

Tags: javascript

I want to add space after capital letter in string of 2d array.

In 2d array we have multiple values, so each value is joined together. 
**example :  ["Title", "GameBook"].** 
we have to make the value separated by space after capital letter.

**output : ["Title", "Game Book"]**

```
let arr = [
  ["Title", "GameBook"],
  ["anyOfYear", 1234],
  ["pieChart", "somePage"],
];

//output => [ [Title, "Game Book"], ["any Of Year", 1234] , ["pie Chart", "some Page"]]
```

How can i achieve the above output that every word will have space after capital letter?

Comment: why "pie Chart" but not "any Of Year"?

Comment: All right, where are you stuck adding the space? Please share your attempt. Why are you using mixed-type arrays to begin with?

Comment: Expected outputs do not match the stated requirements, or even the title of the question.  You're actually adding a space *before* capitals that aren't the first letter and your output is even inconsistent with that, would expect `anyOfYear` -> `any Of Year`

Comment: sorry i had forgotten in output to add space

Comment: `arr.map( (a) => a.map( elem => elem.replaceAll(/\B(?=[A-Z])/g, ' ') ) )`

Comment: Please note that it’s expected that you show what you’ve tried and what isn’t working with your code. Without that, it looks like you’re asking us to write your code for you, and makes your post look low-effort which increases its chance of being closed

Comment: let arr = [
  ["Title", "GameBook"],
  ["anyOfYear", 1234],
  ["pieChart", "somePage"],
];

function spinalCase(str) {
  let lowercase = str.trim();
  let regEx = /\W+|(?=[A-Z])|_/g;
  let result = lowercase.split(regEx).join(" ");
  return result;
}

arr.map((e, i, arr) => {
  e.map((j, k, arr) => {
    if (typeof j === 'string') {
      let output = spinalCase(j);
      arr[k] = output;
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here you can try this logic :**

```js
let arr = [
  ["Title", "GameBook"],
  ["anyOfYear", 1234],
  ["pieChart", "somePage"],
];

arr = arr.map((e) => {
  return e.map((elem) => {
    if (typeof elem == "string") {
      return (elem = elem.replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"));
    }
    return elem;
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This may be correct, but the question is off-topic. Probably best not to answer a no-effort "do my task for me" question. Not sure how this question got +2 and the answer got +2 within minutes, despite being clearly poor quality. Hmm. Even if you do answer, it's a good idea to explain the answer logic rather than the rather pointless "try this".

Comment: Yeah just helping...

Comment: You might be helping the one person that wanted the problem solved, but you are hurting the site.